# Errors with /usr/bin/ld compiling Fortran 77 code

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, linker, fortran, gfortran

Code: https://github.com/CGS-GIS/GPSPACE

OS: Linux 5.6.15-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT x86_64 GNU/Linux

Compiler: gfortran - GNU Fortran (GCC) 10.1.0

Command: `gfortran -std=legacy gpspace.f */*.F -o gpsppp`

Output:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccIvkFdn.o: in function `vmfintrp_':
gpspace.f:(.text+0x27fb7): undefined reference to `vmf1_ht_'
/usr/bin/ld: gpspace.f:(.text+0x27fea): undefined reference to `vmf1_'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccIvkFdn.o: in function `bodyt_':
gpspace.f:(.text+0x34ae9): undefined reference to `dehanttideinel_'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccIvkFdn.o: in function `rderp_':
gpspace.f:(.text+0x36103): undefined reference to `iers_cmp_2015_'
/usr/bin/ld: gpspace.f:(.text+0x3617f): undefined reference to `iers_cmp_2015_'
/usr/bin/ld: gpspace.f:(.text+0x3622e): undefined reference to `iers_cmp_2015_'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccIvkFdn.o: in function `rdmet_':
gpspace.f:(.text+0x367bd): undefined reference to `gpt_'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccIvkFdn.o: in function `MAIN__':
gpspace.f:(.text+0xa750f): undefined reference to `gpt_'
/usr/bin/ld: gpspace.f:(.text+0xacce9): undefined reference to `gmf_'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc9KTZfn.o: in function `oloadn_':
OLOADN.F:(.text+0x242): undefined reference to `admint_'
/usr/bin/ld: OLOADN.F:(.text+0x3ac): undefined reference to `admint_'
/usr/bin/ld: OLOADN.F:(.text+0x516): undefined reference to `admint_'
/usr/bin/ld: OLOADN.F:(.text+0x976): undefined reference to `recurs_'
/usr/bin/ld: OLOADN.F:(.text+0x9ae): undefined reference to `recurs_'
/usr/bin/ld: OLOADN.F:(.text+0x9e6): undefined reference to `recurs_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

No clue what the problem is...

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Please use `LOCALE=C` on the same line before your command to get the error messages in English. To understand what the messages say read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix  (it is about C++ but it works in a similar way in Fortran). There is some more code or library you have to link your code with. To help you any more you will have to provide much more information, see [mcve].

Comment: Note that there are two more subdirectories in the Github repository and they contain more Fortran source files. You will likely have to compile all of them.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirF! I used LC_ALL=C, get error messages in English and updated the post. I will follow taking the tour and reading all the references. I don't know about some more code/library to link. Instructions for Windows compilation with gfortran were just to execute `gfortran -std=legacy gpspace.f */*.F`.

Comment: Don't `*/*.F` include those files?

Comment: It does, sorry. Still you need to satisfy the missing symbols from somwhere.

Comment: You were right! there were some simlinks missing... Thank you!